# Making a movie in MATLAB takes too much RAM and hard disk space... what movie writer should I use?

Tags: matlab, memory, movie, memory-efficient

I am faced with making movies with ~10,000 frames and ~ 10,000 pixels per frame using e.g. `imagesc`. However, even though my computer is equipped with 8 GB of RAM (running 32-bit MATLAB), MATLAB complains with `Out Of Memory` at ~ 1,000 frames. Also, I want my movie compressed as well. What is my best option to create larger movies?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find out what is your best option, I tested several movie writing functions (Windows 7 MATLAB 2012a 32-bit).

### Too long didn't read

The key is to make sure the function flushes frames to disk before the movie is completed. VideoWriter combined with MPEG-4 yields both constant (small) memory size and a compressed video.

### The Code

```
%%%
% General Setup
%%%
number_of_frames = 1000;
Z = peaks; 

%%%
% Video Writer -- AVI
%%%
%%
f = figure('renderer', 'zbuffer');
a = axes('parent', f);
axis(a, 'tight');
surf(a, Z);
current_zlim = zlim();
set(a, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren', 'zlimmode', 'manual', 'zlim', current_zlim);
vid = VideoWriter('myPeaks - VideoWriter.avi');
vid.Quality = 100;
vid.FrameRate = 15;
open(vid);
current_memory_used_Bytes(1, number_of_frames + 1) = 0;
current_memory_struct = memory();
current_memory_used_Bytes(1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
for(k = 1 : number_of_frames)
    surf(a, sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z, Z);
    writeVideo(vid, getframe(f));
    current_memory_struct = memory();
    current_memory_used_Bytes(k + 1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
end
close(vid);
figure;
plot((current_memory_used_Bytes(2 : end) - current_memory_used_Bytes(1)) / 1e6);
xlabel('Frame Number');
ylabel('Movie Memory in RAM (MB)');
title('VideoWriter -- AVI');
saveas(gcf, 'myPeaks - VideoWriter -- AVI.png');
close all;
clearvars -except number_of_frames Z

%%%
% Video Writer -- MPEG-4
%%%
%%
f = figure('renderer', 'zbuffer');
a = axes('parent', f);
axis(a, 'tight');
surf(a, Z);
current_zlim = zlim();
set(a, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren', 'zlimmode', 'manual', 'zlim', current_zlim);
vid = VideoWriter('myPeaks - VideoWriter.mp4', 'MPEG-4');
vid.Quality = 100;
vid.FrameRate = 15;
open(vid);
current_memory_used_Bytes(1, number_of_frames + 1) = 0;
current_memory_struct = memory();
current_memory_used_Bytes(1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
for(k = 1 : number_of_frames)
    surf(a, sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z, Z);
    writeVideo(vid, getframe(f));
    current_memory_struct = memory();
    current_memory_used_Bytes(k + 1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
end
close(vid);
figure;
plot((current_memory_used_Bytes(2 : end) - current_memory_used_Bytes(1)) / 1e6);
xlabel('Frame Number');
ylabel('Movie Memory in RAM (MB)');
title('VideoWriter -- MPEG-4');
saveas(gcf, 'myPeaks - VideoWriter -- MPEG-4.png');
close all;
clearvars -except number_of_frames Z

%%%
% Movie2AVI
%%%
%%
f = figure('renderer', 'zbuffer');
a = axes('parent', f);
axis(a, 'tight');
surf(a, Z);
current_zlim = zlim();
set(a, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren', 'zlimmode', 'manual', 'zlim', current_zlim);
movie_frames(1 : number_of_frames) = struct('cdata', [], 'colormap', []);
current_memory_used_Bytes(1, number_of_frames + 1) = 0;
current_memory_struct = memory();
current_memory_used_Bytes(1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
for(k = 1 : number_of_frames)
    surf(a, sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z, Z);
    movie_frames(k) = getframe(f);
    current_memory_struct = memory();
    current_memory_used_Bytes(k + 1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
end
movie2avi(movie_frames, 'myPeaks - Movie2AVI.avi', 'compression', 'none', 'fps', 10);
figure;
plot((current_memory_used_Bytes(2 : end) - current_memory_used_Bytes(1)) / 1e6);
xlabel('Frame Number');
ylabel('Movie Memory in RAM (MB)');
title('Movie2AVI -- AVI');
saveas(gcf, 'myPeaks - Movie2AVI -- AVI.png');
close all;
clearvars -except number_of_frames Z

%%%
% IMWrite
%%%
%%
f = figure('renderer', 'zbuffer');
a = axes('parent', f);
axis(a, 'tight');
surf(a, Z);
current_zlim = zlim();
set(a, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren', 'zlimmode', 'manual', 'zlim', current_zlim);
current_frame = getframe(a);
[frame_indices, cmap] = rgb2ind(current_frame.cdata, 256, 'nodither');
movie_frames = repmat(frame_indices, [1 1 1 number_of_frames]);
current_memory_used_Bytes(1, number_of_frames + 1) = 0;
current_memory_struct = memory();
current_memory_used_Bytes(1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
for(k = 1 : number_of_frames)
    surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z, Z)
    f = getframe(a);
    movie_frames(:, :, 1, k) = rgb2ind(f.cdata, cmap, 'nodither');
    current_memory_struct = memory();
    current_memory_used_Bytes(k + 1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
end
imwrite(movie_frames, cmap, 'myPeaks - IMWrite.gif', 'DelayTime', 0, 'LoopCount', inf);
figure;
plot((current_memory_used_Bytes(2 : end) - current_memory_used_Bytes(1)) / 1e6);
xlabel('Frame Number');
ylabel('Movie Memory in RAM (MB)');
title('Movie2AVI -- AVI');
saveas(gcf, 'myPeaks - IMWrite.png');
close all;
clearvars -except number_of_frames Z

%%%
% MPGWrite
%%%
%%
f = figure('renderer', 'zbuffer');
a = axes('parent', f);
axis(a, 'tight');
surf(a, Z);
current_zlim = zlim();
set(a, 'nextplot', 'replacechildren', 'zlimmode', 'manual', 'zlim', current_zlim);
winsize = get(f, 'Position');
winsize(1:2) = [0 0];
movie_frames = moviein(number_of_frames, f, winsize);
current_memory_used_Bytes(1, number_of_frames + 1) = 0;
current_memory_struct = memory();
current_memory_used_Bytes(1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
for(k = 1 : number_of_frames)
    surf(sin(2*pi*k/20)*Z, Z)
    drawnow;
    movie_frames(:, k) = im2frame(hardcopy(f, '-Dzbuffer', '-r0')); 
    current_memory_struct = memory();
    current_memory_used_Bytes(k + 1) = current_memory_struct.MemUsedMATLAB;
end
mpgwrite(movie_frames, jet, 'myPeaks - MPGWrite.mpg');
figure;
plot((current_memory_used_Bytes(2 : end) - current_memory_used_Bytes(1)) / 1e6);
xlabel('Frame Number');
ylabel('Movie Memory in RAM (MB)');
title('MPGWrite -- MPG');
saveas(gcf, 'myPeaks - MPGWrite.png');
close all;
clearvars -except number_of_frames Z
```

### The Results

#### Memory vs. Frame Number

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As we can see, VideoWriter, IMWrite and Movie2AVI have nearly constant memory requirements, while the memory necessary for AVI2File and MPGWrite scales with the number of frames. This makes sense as the latter require holding every frame before writing the movie, while the former appear to flush to disk regularly.

#### Movie Size

VideoWriter -- AVI: 154,529 KB

VideoWriter -- MPEG-4: 19,355 KB

IMWrite: 13,385 KB

Movie2AVI -- AVI: 992,276 KB

MPGWrite: 24,301 KB

MPEG-4 yields a much more efficient compression than AVI, as expected. Interestingly, VideoWriter and IMWrite both outperform MPGWrite on this test (though I give credit to MPGWrite for coming many years before VideoWriter!).

Comment: It might be helpful to mention which `version` of Matlab this is with. The `VideoWriter` class has changed some since it's introduction. Also, what OS did you use? The video codecs that `VideoWriter` uses are heavily dependent on OS.

Comment: Ahh ... I see that your code uses `memory`, which is a Windows-only function. Unfortunately your solution is not cross platform.

Comment: Unfortunately, [alternatives to `memory`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/profiling-matlab-memory-usage/) are undocumented. If you can suggest a documented/cross-platform alternative to `memory`, I'm all ears. Also, just wrote down the version of MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most powerful, consistent, and flexible method of making videos from MATLAB plots is by exporting individual frames as images and then combining the images into a movie with another program such as ffmpeg. This also gives you the opportunity to batch process the images if desired. I created a full writeup of the process which you can find here: http://enstrophy.mae.ufl.edu/~mohseni/links/docs/video_guide.pdf

Comment: Interesting alternative... if anyone can suggest a command-line version of `convert` for Windows (or alternative) then I could try this method.

Comment: @PeterD ImageMagick provides `convert` and many other utilities and is available for Windows, OSX and Linux. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows